# News about Edwin?

Tags: discussion

Does anyone know anything about user [Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth)? A somewhat exigent and at times infuriating stickler for standards, I find myself missing his droll comments. He's been “missing” since July.

Comment: One of his last comments (here) was about [*being found to be missing*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/453842/to-go-missing-versus-to-turn-up-missing-versus-to-take-missing#comment1093030_453842). Coincidence?

Comment: @JJJ ... that's creepy. Of course, it's coincidence.

Comment: He’s been inactive for long periods  of time before, and finally always came back. I really don’t miss him but he will eventually turn up again also this time.

Comment: @user240918  it's nearly four months...

Comment: Sad that users should downvote someone's concern about a fellow member. What does that tell us and visitors about this community?

Comment: @Mari-LouA +13 -2 tells us that they are in the minority, and that the community cares about its long-standing members going missing.

Comment: I wouldn't say you were a stickler for standards, Mari-Lou. But Edwin is.

Comment: @TimLymington I meant him of course. But I see how it *could* be misinterpreted. Thank you for nit-picking and making sure standards are kept high :P

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It tells us that this site is behaving as it always has. EL&U seems to partake of a mixture of broad collegiality seasoned with acute dyspepsia.

Comment: Now I wonder what words you’d use to describe me if I go missing. Maybe ... prolix.

Comment: @Dan Bron  Maverick fits you better than prolix.

Comment: @ab2 Haha! I’ll take it. Always wanted to be a bad boy, stealing hearts and riding Harleys.

Comment: I suppose we wouldn’t be expecting any more definitive responses unless Edwin returns, but I just wanted to drop you a note saying, “Good on you for asking”.

Comment: This kind of question should be asked in the chat room(s).

Comment: @Knotell why? Are you offended? Do you think chat is more private?

Comment: Hi, @Mari-LouA I only just posted a Q which I _know_ is a [duplicate to yours](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11989/does-anyone-know-where-edwin-is), and I thought I was just trying to get an update (Where is Edwin?). But I got kicked fairly hard in the chops with basically the non-answer answer that you objected to. I was told: "I've marked this as a duplicate because MetaEd's answer on the other question is definitive.", but that was not an answer. As you had pointed out. So what's happening? Are we being overly-nosy?

Comment: @Cascabel there was no need to post the same question. I find the topic now distressful. I am hoping everything is fine, but the silence and his continual absence is telling me a different story.

Comment: FWIW...I did a search in the obits of the Oldham Times, Funeral-Notices.co.UK, (the other rags in the area are less user-friendly), and I got nothing. So...I am thinking now it was a personal decision to leave off contributing for a while. I hope this helps put your mind at ease.

Comment: [He's back](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/498510/when-do-i-put-a-comma-after-a-city-name#comment1202664_498510) :-)

Comment: It appears my comment was appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tools to check on this. Here's a click as of this morning.

[image: Edwin Ashworth in the flesh, 2019-05-21]

Comment: A few of us have already welcomed him back since his return on 17th (I think). Hooray for Edwin!

Answer (score 6):

It's likely that anyone who knows would say nothing out of a respect for user privacy. Unless we hear from him personally, I think this is the answer to your question.

(From this perspective, when you ask if the two downvotes on the question show lack of concern, actually the opposite might be true.)

Comment: Oh, so they were telling me to mind my own business. Possible.... I suppose they could even be justified thinking that. But I would only like to know if he is well. I hope he is.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It was a kind gesture on your part, and I doubt there is anybody who would disagree with that.

Comment: Downvoting this question out of concern for user privacy is perverse.  First, because a genuine concern when a user disappears is natural and collegial.  Ignoring a prolonged absence of a prominent user is callous.  Second, because, if true, it implies that the reason is an unhappy one.  So, I think the downvoters are downvoting simply because they can, not for any admirable reason.

Comment: @JJJ You have a point.  But in the 3.5 years I have been a user here, I remember only one permanent unexplained disappearance or retirement.   Possibly there were others, and I didn't know users well enough to realize they had gone.  So I don't think we are at the point yet where a long absence must be shrugged off .   Perhaps a good model is the Class Notes section of a university magazine, where people  write in notes about themselves -- or don't.

Comment: @JJJ Science Fiction and Fantasy asked people on their Meta to write a few sentences on how they got started on the SFF site -- a delayed birth announcement, so to speak.

Comment: @JJJ "*…it's not really feasible to voice concern for every user's disappearance…*" do you know how many users have got off the radar since I joined? Kosmonaut for one thing. This is the first–and probably the last time–I have plucked the courage (yes, sometimes it has to be plucked!) to ask members if they have any news of a respected and esteemed member.

Comment: Meta Ed, you didn't answer the original question. You instead provided an explanation, or a justification, for the few downvotes. So, because I think you *do* know something, is Edwin going to come back?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I answered your question, and added a related comment about the downvotes. Sorry I did not make this distinction clear. I've edited.

Comment: What if he is dead? Would users in the know still keep us in the dark? Is he dead?

Comment: @Knotell I don't know -- or even suspect -- anything. There isn't any point in discussing this further, until someone has new information.

Comment: I was actually hoping someone would say that Edwin had enough of EL&U and was taking a sabbatical. Or that he was recovering from a bad case of flu or pneumonia, or he had to tend to personal family affairs, something like that. Nothing macabre.

Comment: He's back! I am so so pleased, I'd still be happy even if he downvoted my answers. I wouldn't care in the least. Edwin is well.